# Rotate image by 90, 180 or 270 degrees

Tags: java, opencv, rotation

I need to rotate an image by either 90, 180 or 270 degrees.  In OpenCV4Android I can use:

```
Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(new Point(center, center), degrees, 1);
Imgproc.warpAffine(src, dst, rotationMatrix, dst.size());
```

However, this is a huge bottleneck in my image processing algorithm.  Of course, a simple rotation by a multiple of 90 degrees is much simpler than the most general case of `warpAffine`, and can be done much more efficiently.  For 180 degrees, for instance, I could use:

```
Core.flip(src, dst, -1);
```

where -1 means to flip about both horizontal and vertical axes.  Is there a similar optimization I could use for 90 or 270 degree rotations?

Comment: have you concluded the java solution , can you post the same

Comment: both `Core.rotate(mRgba, mRgba, Core.ROTATE_180);` & `Core.flip(mRgba, mRgba, -1);` will eat about ~12-14 ms CPU on my Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime. very bad performance. I wanted to inverse camera byte frames but it's too much

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the first result when you Google it and none of these solutions really answer the question or is correct or succinct.

```
Core.rotate(Mat src, Mat dst, Core.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE); //ROTATE_180 or ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE
```

Comment: Wow, a re-assigned answer!

Answer (score 46):

I don't know the Java API very well, this code are developed in c++.
The logics should be the same, use transpose + flip to rotate the image with
90n(n belongs to N = -minimum value of int, ....., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., max value of int)

```cpp
/*
 *@brief rotate image by multiple of 90 degrees
 *
 *@param source : input image
 *@param dst : output image
 *@param angle : factor of 90, even it is not factor of 90, the angle
 * will be mapped to the range of [-360, 360].
 * {angle = 90n; n = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} }
 * if angle bigger than 360 or smaller than -360, the angle will
 * be map to -360 ~ 360.
 * mapping rule is : angle = ((angle / 90) % 4) * 90;
 *
 * ex : 89 will map to 0, 98 to 90, 179 to 90, 270 to 3, 360 to 0.
 *
 */
void rotate_image_90n(cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, int angle)
{   
   if(src.data != dst.data){
       src.copyTo(dst);
   }

   angle = ((angle / 90) % 4) * 90;

   //0 : flip vertical; 1 flip horizontal
   bool const flip_horizontal_or_vertical = angle > 0 ? 1 : 0;
   int const number = std::abs(angle / 90);          

   for(int i = 0; i != number; ++i){
       cv::transpose(dst, dst);
       cv::flip(dst, dst, flip_horizontal_or_vertical);
   }
}
```

Edit : Improve performance, thanks for the comments of TimZaman and the implementation of 1''

```cpp
void rotate_90n(cv::Mat const &src, cv::Mat &dst, int angle)
{        
     CV_Assert(angle % 90 == 0 && angle <= 360 && angle >= -360);
     if(angle == 270 || angle == -90){
        // Rotate clockwise 270 degrees
        cv::transpose(src, dst);
        cv::flip(dst, dst, 0);
    }else if(angle == 180 || angle == -180){
        // Rotate clockwise 180 degrees
        cv::flip(src, dst, -1);
    }else if(angle == 90 || angle == -270){
        // Rotate clockwise 90 degrees
        cv::transpose(src, dst);
        cv::flip(dst, dst, 1);
    }else if(angle == 360 || angle == 0 || angle == -360){
        if(src.data != dst.data){
            src.copyTo(dst);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop makes it more expensive than necessary mate.

Comment: I am not fond of the temporary image created by `src.t()`: it causes every time an allocation which could be expensive especially in Android

Comment: @Antonio The create function will only allocate new buffer when needed. In other words, it would not allocate anything if the dimensions and type of the dst same as src

Comment: Sure, but I am speaking about the matrix created when calling `src.t()`

Comment: @Antonio Thanks for pointing out src.t(), I use transpose to replace it, now it would not allocate new buffer if the dst and src have same size and type

Comment: @StereoMatching I am afraid flip with same source and dest will cause an allocation. I might be wrong, it would be necessary to check opencv source code.

Comment: @Antonio Do not worry, flip do not need to allocate memory if the size and type of the dst same as src. The codes are located at core/copy.cpp

Comment: @StereoMatching You are totally right! One funny note: The only thing in which it will not work is if the 2 input Mats are 2 partially overlapping sub-Mats of the same Mat, but that's just a crazy case!

Comment: (1) `dst.create(src.size(), src.type());` isn't needed. (2) if a wrong degree integer is passed, `dst` will be created with memory garbage. either assert or catch that or use flag integers (3) use `const` in passing src variable.

Answer (score 9):

This will rotate an image any number of degrees, using the most efficient means for multiples of 90.

```
    void
    rotate_cw(const cv::Mat& image, cv::Mat& dest, int degrees)
    {
        switch (degrees % 360) {
            case 0:
                dest = image.clone();
                break;
            case 90:
                cv::flip(image.t(), dest, 1);
                break;
            case 180:
                cv::flip(image, dest, -1);
                break;
            case 270:
                cv::flip(image.t(), dest, 0);
                break;
            default:
                cv::Mat r = cv::getRotationMatrix2D({image.cols/2.0F, image.rows/2.0F}, degrees, 1.0);
                int len = std::max(image.cols, image.rows);
                cv::warpAffine(image, dest, r, cv::Size(len, len));
                break; //image size will change
        }
    }
```

But with opencv 3.0, this is done by just via the [cv::rotate](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4ad01c0978b0ce64baa246811deeac24) command:

```
cv::rotate(image, dest, e.g. cv::ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE);
```

Comment: Usually the output image should be passed as parameter, otherwise allocation will happen at each call. (With your implementation you have only an advantage in the case of rotation = 0)

Comment: Pff this code is dangerous. You are returning the same underlying data as is passed in `image`, unless the rotation is default. Moreover, the canvas generated is too big due to `cv::Size(len, len)`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I edited and ported your first solution [0,90,180,270] for android where I had an OpenCV app and I could show the JavaCameraView in the right way. Have a good day!

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using the Android API.  Here, I am using it to rotate images from a camera which could be mounted in various orientations.

```
if (mCameraOrientation == 270) {
    // Rotate clockwise 270 degrees
    Core.flip(src.t(), dst, 0);
} else if (mCameraOrientation == 180) {
    // Rotate clockwise 180 degrees
    Core.flip(src, dst, -1);
} else if (mCameraOrientation == 90) {
    // Rotate clockwise 90 degrees
    Core.flip(src.t(), dst, 1);
} else if (mCameraOrientation == 0) {
    // No rotation
    dst = src;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my Python translation (and thanks to all the posters):

```
import cv2
def rot90(img, rotflag):
    """ rotFlag 1=CW, 2=CCW, 3=180"""
    if rotflag == 1:
        img = cv2.transpose(img)  
        img = cv2.flip(img, 1)  # transpose+flip(1)=CW
    elif rotflag == 2:
        img = cv2.transpose(img)  
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)  # transpose+flip(0)=CCW
    elif rotflag ==3:
        img = cv2.flip(img, -1)  # transpose+flip(-1)=180
    elif rotflag != 0:  # if not 0,1,2,3
        raise Exception("Unknown rotation flag({})".format(rotflag))
    return img
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this Python version using `Numpy` only, which are much faster than using `cv2.transpose()` and `cv2.flip()`.

```
def rotate_image_90(im, angle):
    if angle % 90 == 0:
        angle = angle % 360
        if angle == 0:
            return im
        elif angle == 90:
            return im.transpose((1,0, 2))[:,::-1,:]
        elif angle == 180:
            return im[::-1,::-1,:]
        elif angle == 270:
            return im.transpose((1,0, 2))[::-1,:,:]

    else:
        raise Exception('Error')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate image using numpy `rot90` function

like

```
def rotate_image(image,deg):
    if deg ==90:
        return np.rot90(image)
    if deg ==180:
        return np.rot90(image,2)
    if deg == 270:
        return np.rot90(image,-1) #Reverse 90 deg rotation
```

Hope this help ..

Comment: Both the `rot90` function and its `k` (times) parameters are superb. This means reverse 90 deg can be also written as `np.rot90(image, 3)`.

Comment: There's a little gotcha - the result is an array view, which is not contiguous. `imshow` has no problem with that, but the drawing functions can throw this: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels). It can be fixed with `np.ascontiguousarray`.

Comment: Note: this answer shows **python/numpy** while the question shows **java**

Answer (score 0):

Use the `numpy.rot90`,if you want 180 degrees,just do it twice.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.png',1)
cv2.imshow('',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

img90 = np.rot90(img)
cv2.imshow('',img90)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
(ret, image_original) = vs.read()
image_rotated_90 = np.rot90(image_original)
image_rotated_180 = np.rot90(image_rotated_90)

# show the frame and press any key to quit the image frame
cv2.imshow("Frame", image_rotated_180)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here's a function to rotate by any angle `[-360 ... 360]`

```
def rotate_image(image, angle):
    # Grab the dimensions of the image and then determine the center
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
    (cX, cY) = (w / 2, h / 2)

    # Grab the rotation matrix (applying the negative of the
    # angle to rotate clockwise), then grab the sine and cosine
    # (i.e., the rotation components of the matrix)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), -angle, 1.0)
    cos = np.abs(M[0, 0])
    sin = np.abs(M[0, 1])

    # Compute the new bounding dimensions of the image
    nW = int((h * sin) + (w * cos))
    nH = int((h * cos) + (w * sin))

    # Adjust the rotation matrix to take into account translation
    M[0, 2] += (nW / 2) - cX
    M[1, 2] += (nH / 2) - cY

    # Perform the actual rotation and return the image
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (nW, nH))
```

Usage

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
rotate = rotate_image(image, angle=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

Noone notices this simple method. use `cv2.rotate` to rotate the image 90 degrees in clockwise

```
image = cv2.rotate(src, cv2.cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
```

Other flags

> ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE Python: cv.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE

> ROTATE_180  Python: cv.ROTATE_180

> ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE  Python: cv.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE

cv2 official link https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4ad01c0978b0ce64baa246811deeac24