# Image rotation(by 90 degress) in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix

Can anyone suggest me how to rotate an image by 90 degrees? any implemented function in opencv?

i think transpose of an image is totally different from 90 degree rotation (both clockwise and anti-clockwise)

Comment: transpose and flip...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate Opencv Matrix by 90, 180, 270 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043152/rotate-opencv-matrix-by-90-180-270-degrees)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the most efficient way, but it's so easy

cv::transpose(img, res);

cv::flip(res, res, 1);