# JavaCV or OpenCV Image Rotation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv, image-rotation

My objective is to rotate an image by a certain angle (e.g. 30 degrees). One possible way of rotating by 90 degrees in OpenCV is given by [tenta4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696765/image-rotationby-90-degress-in-opencv) but unfortunately, it only performs 90-degree flips.

Another possible way is a method "SkewGrayImage" given in [JavaCV samples](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/BlobDemo.java) where it performs "small angle rotations" that appear to work for rotations of up to approximately 45 - 50 degrees but not for any other higher values.

So - my issues is, is there a proper way/method in OpenCV or JavaCV to actually perform an angular rotation of images or objects?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d4/d61/tutorial_warp_affine.html) for a C++ example.

Answer (score 4):

[Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299267/image-scaling-and-rotating-in-c-c) has explained how to compute a rotation matrix with respect to the center of the image and then to perform a rotation as follows:

```
    Mat rotated_image;
    warpAffine(src, rotated_image, rot_mat, src.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

there is an operation that's called warp, and it is able to just rotate, but also to do some other transformations on the image.

Some useful links are here

- https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/modules/stitching/doc/warpers.html
- https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d29/group__cudawarping.html
- https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

A more detailed answer for IplImage rotation is given by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289690/opencv-how-to-rotate-iplimage) based on Mat variables which can then be converted and returned as an IplImage as follows:

```
Mat source = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat rotation_matrix = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, angle, 1.0);
Mat destinationMat;
warpAffine(source, destinationMat, rotation_matrix, source.size());
IplImage iplframe = IplImage(destinationMat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps! Worked for me with JavaCV.

```
Mat raw = ... // your raw mat

// Create your "new" Mat and the center of your Raw Mat
Mat result = new Mat(raw.size(), [your Image Type]); // my Img type was CV_8U
Point2f rawCenter = new Point2f(raw.cols() / 2.0F, raw.rows() / 2.0F);

// Scale and Rotation of new Mat
double scale = 1.0;
int rotation = -5;

// Rotation Matrix
Mat rotationMatrix = getRotationMatrix2D(rawCenter, rotation, scale);

// Rotate 
warpAffine(raw, result, rotationMatrix, raw.size());
```