# Image loses quality with cv2.warpPerspective

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-rotation, opencv3.1

I am working with OpenCV 3.1 and with Python.

My problem comes when I try to deskew (fix the tilt of) an image with text. I am using `cv2.warpPerspective` to make it possible, but the image loses a lot of quality. You can see here the original part of the image:

[image: image without smooth]

and then, here, the "rotated" image:

[image: image with smooth]

it is like *smoothed*.

I was using morphological transformation like:

```
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
blur_image = cv2.erode(tresh, kernel, iterations=1)
```

and

```
white_mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(white_mask2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

to see if it improves something, but nothing.

I saw [this example here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656698/perspective-correction-in-opencv-using-python), but those guys had the same problem:
[image] and [image]

So, I don't have idea what can I do. 
Maybe there is a way to not losing the quality of the image, or, there's another method to rotate the image without quality lost. 
I know this method:

```
root_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(to_rotate_center, angle, 1.0)
result = cv2.warpAffine(to_rotate, root_mat, to_rotate.shape, flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

But it doesn't work for me, as I have to rotate every rectangle here:

[image]

and not the whole image. It means, the best way I found to do it, was `warpPerspective`, and it works fine, but with quality loss. I would appreciate an advice to avoid the quality lost.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is related to the interpolation required by the warping. If you don't want things to appear smoother, you should switch from default interpolation method, which is `INTER_LINEAR` to another one, such as `INTER_NEAREST`. It would help you with the sharpness of the edges.

Try `flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST` on your `warp` call, be it [warpAffine()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.warpAffine) or [warpPerspective()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#cv2.warpPerspective).

Interpolation flags are listed [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

```
enum InterpolationFlags { 
    INTER_NEAREST = 0, 
    INTER_LINEAR = 1, 
    INTER_CUBIC = 2, 
    INTER_AREA = 3, 
    INTER_LANCZOS4 = 4, 
    INTER_MAX = 7, 
    WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS = 8, 
    WARP_INVERSE_MAP = 16 
}
```

Comment: Beautiful man! Thank you :) The problem was with the cv2.INTER_LINEAR.

Comment: For more background info about the differences between these interpolation methods, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_gallery_of_image_scaling_algorithms and https://tanalin.com/en/articles/integer-scaling/