# low quality image with cv2.warperspective

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I am working with the perspective transformation using opencv on python. So I have found the homography matrix between two sets of points using SIFT detector. For now, I would like to transform an image using the cv2.warperspective function but it turns out the quality of the warped image is very low.

I did some google search and found this, [Image loses quality with cv2.warpPerspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371507/image-loses-quality-with-cv2-warpperspective). So by using the method from the accepted answer which try with different interpolation flags for the warperspective but it didn't help. Please do suggest what to do to overcome the issue. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import copy

def main():
    picture = cv2.imread("src/paper.png")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("src/video0.mp4")
    query = cv2.imread("src/qr.png")

    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        h,w = frame.shape[:2]
        rgb = cv2.cvtColor(query, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        paper = cv2.resize(paper, (query.shape[1], query.shape[0]), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # declare sift object detector
        sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

        # point and object detection
        query_kp, query_des = sift.detectAndCompute(rgb,None)
        train_kp, train_des = sift.detectAndCompute(frame.astype(np.uint8),None)

        match_points = []
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2,crossCheck=False)
        match = bf.knnMatch(query_des,train_des,k=2)
        # ratio test
        ratio = 0.8
        for ptn1,ptn2 in match:
            if ptn1.distance < ratio * ptn2.distance:
                match_points.append(ptn1)

        # at least 4 points for projection
        if len(match_points) >= 4:
            set_point1 = np.float32([query_kp[ptn.queryIdx].pt for ptn in match_points]).reshape((-1, 1, 2))
            set_point2 = np.float32([train_kp[ptn.trainIdx].pt for ptn in match_points]).reshape((-1, 1, 2))
            frame = projection(frame, paper, set_point1, set_point2)

        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)


def projection(frame, picture, set_point1, set_point2):
    h,w = frame.shape[:2]
    homography_matrix, _ = cv2.findHomography(set_point1,set_point2,cv2.RANSAC,5)
    warpedImg = cv2.warpPerspective(picture, homography_matrix, (w,h), flags=cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

    # overlay the warpedImg to original frame
    x,y,z = np.where(warpedImg != [0,0,0])
    frame[x,y,z] = warpedImg[x,y,z]
    return frame

main()
```

Example output - The image under the profile picture section (I understand due to the aspect ratio so it looks small but the quality is just bad and the words in the warped image are all kinda distorted):
[image]

Comment: you need to pass interpolation flags to `warp*`. NOTE: the warps don't support INTER_AREA, they implement that as INTER_LINEAR. when you have to downscale something, lowpass it beforehand.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Hi, thanks for the reply. Do you mean I need to pass the interpolation flag for warpPerspective to any warp* method? Also, I don't quite get the idea of lowpass it before downscaling, could you please elaborate more on it? Thank you.

Comment: Please post your input and output images so we can see the input quality and the output quality

Answer (score 1):

did you test various interpolation methods, supported in OpenCV? I reckon that the results of bilinear or bicubic interpolation (i.e., **INTER_LINEAR** or **INTER_CUBIC**) would be surprising for you. You can change your code as below (indeed you are are using **INTER_NEAREST** which can distort image contents):

```
warpedImg = cv2.warpPerspective(picture, homography_matrix, (w,h), flags= cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS + cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

From OpenCV source:

```
enum InterpolationFlags{
    /** nearest neighbor interpolation */
    INTER_NEAREST        = 0,
    /** bilinear interpolation */
    INTER_LINEAR         = 1,
    /** bicubic interpolation */
    INTER_CUBIC          = 2,
    /** resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation, as
    it gives moire'-free results. But when the image is zoomed, it is similar to the INTER_NEAREST
    method. */
    INTER_AREA           = 3,
    /** Lanczos interpolation over 8x8 neighborhood */
    INTER_LANCZOS4       = 4,
    /** Bit exact bilinear interpolation */
    INTER_LINEAR_EXACT = 5,
    /** Bit exact nearest neighbor interpolation. This will produce same results as
    the nearest neighbor method in PIL, scikit-image or Matlab. */
    INTER_NEAREST_EXACT  = 6,
    /** mask for interpolation codes */
    INTER_MAX            = 7,
    /** flag, fills all of the destination image pixels. If some of them correspond to outliers in the
    source image, they are set to zero */
    WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS   = 8,
    /** flag, inverse transformation

    For example, #linearPolar or #logPolar transforms:
    - flag is __not__ set: \f$dst( \rho , \phi ) = src(x,y)\f$
    - flag is set: \f$dst(x,y) = src( \rho , \phi )\f$
    */
    WARP_INVERSE_MAP     = 16
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try with that and the quality has improved a bit with the combination of multiple interpolation flags. But still the result is not very satisfied, so turns out I try to set the font size to bigger for better quality.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned higher input resolution would improve the result, albeit if you don’t have any speed issues. The point which seems suspicious about your response is that, as far as I know, just one of the interpolation flags will be applied in OpenCV, and a combination of them has no effect. You can see the OpenCV source code to check which interpolation method is really applied based on your input.