# OpenCV-How to rotate captured video from camera

Tags: opencv

I have OpenCV project using C language.  I wish to rotate the captured video from camera, how I can do that?  What is the rotate function in OpenCV?  My code as below

```
static CvCapture * cap;

cap = cvCaptureFromCAM(cam_index);

Flip(cap, 0);
```

But it got error.  How I can  rotate my video?  Please help

Comment: Just use `cvWarpAffine` https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#warpaffine, I guest :)

Comment: and what is the error? are you sure you are getting images?

Comment: I'm able to flip it now, just it only flip 180 degree.  Not able to flip 90 degree.  How I can flip 90 degree.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy  do you have any similar project in C language can share for me as reference?  Thanks

Comment: @DerickLoo It's just some simple lines code. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15043287/5832644

Answer (score 0):

You would rotate the video frame by frame. First, using [`getRotationMatrix2D()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gafbbc470ce83812914a70abfb604f4326) you get the rotation matrix, then using [`warpAffine()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983) rotate each frame.

```
Mat image = imread("test.jpg");
Mat rot = getRotationMatrix2D(Point2f(image.cols/2.0, image.rows/2.0), angle, 1.0);
Mat rotated;
warpAffine(image, rotated, rot, image.size());
```

Comment: How I can use this 2 function in C language?  Any similar project in C language can share to me as reference?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DerickLoo see the code snippet I've added to the answer.